# Using archunit to enforce log context

Tags: java, junit5, archunit

Following the method suggested in [this](https://shekhargulati.com/2022/10/08/enforcing-logging-best-practices-by-writing-archunit-tests/) blog post, I am trying to create an archunit rule that will enforce log statements to have contextual information. But the code mentioned in the example is not compiling:

```java
public static ArchRule noInfoLoggingWithoutContext() {
        ArchCondition<JavaClass> loggerWithOutContext =
                callMethodWhere(
                        target(name("info"))
                                .and(target(owner(assignableTo(Logger.class))))
                                .and(target(rawParameterTypes(new DescribedPredicate<>("logger.info without context") {
                                    @Override
                                    public boolean test(List<JavaClass> methodParameters) {
                                        return methodParameters.size() <= 1;
                                    }
                                })))).as("use logger.info without context");
        return noClasses().should(loggerWithOutContext);
 }
```

The above mentioned code fails with the following error:

```java
Required type: DescribedPredicate <? super AccessTarget>
Provided: DescribedPredicate<HasParameterTypes>
```

Any suggestions, how can we implement such a rule?

archunit version: 1.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably picked the "wrong" static import

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaAccess.Predicates.target;
```

(which returns a `DescribedPredicate<JavaAccess<?>>`) instead of

```java
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaCall.Predicates.target;
```

(which returns a `DescribedPredicate<JavaCall<?>>`).

As `callMethodWhere` takes a `DescribedPredicate<? super JavaMethodCall>`,
and as `JavaMethodCall extends JavaCall`, which in turn `extends JavaCodeUnitAccess`, which in turn `extends JavaAccess`, the "wrong" `target` method worked for `callMethodWhere`, but its predicates could only operate on `JavaAccess`, which has a `name` and an `owner`, but no `rawParameterTypes`.

---

Unrelated to your question: I would simplify the entire rule to

```java
import com.tngtech.archunit.junit.ArchTest;
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

import static com.tngtech.archunit.base.DescribedPredicate.describe;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaCall.Predicates.target;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchConditions.callMethodWhere;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchPredicates.is;
import static com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.noClasses;

public class StackOverflow76250573 {

    @ArchTest
    ArchRule noInfoLoggingWithoutContext =
        noClasses().should(callMethodWhere(target(is(describe("logger.info without context",
            target ->
                target.getOwner().isAssignableTo(Logger.class)
                    && target.getName().equals("info")
                    && target.getRawParameterTypes().size() < 2
        )))));
}
```